# Is it possible to represent any arbitrary game as a 2 player game?

Tags: game-theory

[I'm sorry that I wasn't more specific. Please bare with me I'm a curious novice and a new comer here to stack exchange.]

original question: "Is it possible to represent any arbitrary game as a 2 player game regardless of the number of players there actually are by treating cooperating players as a single player?"

I think the main thing I'm trying to say here is.. when players work together is it possible just to consider them to be a player with an extended strategy space or to consider all players that are not working with a target player to be a single enemy.

I have an intuition but lack the skill to formalize it.

I'll try an example. 3 player Paper, Scissor, Rock.

The typical strategy space is;
P, S, R for any player
but say that two players were working together
Then could we say they have a strategy space that looks like PP, PS, PR, .., RR?

Is this even possible?
.and if so, then is it possible that any game at all is actually just a two player game?

Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: Can you make this question more specific?

Comment: In your example, the two player game is well defined, but what do you mean by the three player game? Do you win by picking something that beats both other players, so you cannot win if the others do not agree?  If collaboration means they form a team and always do the best for the team, you can consider them one player.  Often collaboration is much less restrictive than that.  Each player still has his/her own objective and pursues it, maybe sharing information with others on the team.

Comment: Thank you the comment regarding collaboration actually answers my question. :)